# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found after installing maven in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I Am following a Tutorial on you tube and i come across an error which i have no clue about.
i am not able to proceed what ever is in the tutorial unless i resolve this issue.

Created simple servlet with

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("COntrol is here with me");
    PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
    out.println("Helloo dunya");
```

when i run this code it doesn't find the class and give 404 not found
how ever if i call same servlett from jspFile . The jsp works fine but after clicking on Login Button which action is also on Login . it give the same error.

In short Tomcat is not able to fine Servlet

Package name: Com.Example.Login
Servletname: Login

```
Web.xml : have this code

<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>Login</display-name>
<servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Com.Example.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

the error is
404 not found with the exception

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [Login]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Com.Example.Login
```

and so on

please try to help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide all information that you have. In this case this would mean to include at least the complete class source and your directory structure, instead of just one method.

Comment: It is a java class path issue. Check your class path.

Comment: can you post the full code, comprehensive of the package name, of the Login class?

Answer (score 0):

According to the information that you have provided here, I guess its the problem with your package name and the class name,

first check whether your package name is correct?
whether its

> Com.Example.Login

or

> com.example.login

And if its correct as you have mentioned here,

then check your `<servlet-class>Com.Example.Login</servlet-class>` in web.xml file 
this tag should refer to the exact class (the servlet)

So as you have mentioned here your package is

> Com.Example.Login

and your class is

> Login

your configuration should change as, 
`<servlet-class>Com.Example.Login.Login</servlet-class>`
(referring to the exact servlet class)
This should fix your error and please be informed that there are standards for package naming and there are really good reasons to them as well. Please refer them to increase your code quality. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)